# While loop not completing properly

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, counting

Ok, so I'm trying to keep score of the times a function is run within a while loop until the condition is met. It is not working out so well. When the while loop starts it seems to take forever to complete and crashes, when it should only take two runs of the loop. Any advice?

Here's what I have so far:

```
void reverseArray (int arr[], int m){
    int arr2 [100000000];

    for (int i = m-1, d = 0; i >= 0;i--, d++)
        arr2[d] = arr[i];

    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
        arr[i] = arr2[i];

}

int main (){ // score, score = time number is reversed
    int points=0, n, m;
    int arr[10];


    scanf ("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the array elements\n");

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    m = arr[0];

    while (m!=1){
        void revereseArray (int arr[], int m);
        points ++;
    }

    printf ("\n\n%d", points);
}
```

The point of this is to take an array and reassemble it until the first element is equal to 1. I also have to see how many times I have to run the function until the first element is equal to 1.

Now, I don't have to run the function inside a while loop, just until the condition is met.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues with your code. The first, which prevents your `while` loop from finishing at all, is that you don't actually change the value of `m` in your loop. Therefore, the loop runs forever and cannot terminate.

The line

```
void revereseArray (int arr[], int m);
```

is not a function call, but a *function declaration* for a function called `revereseArray`. It doesn't do anything inside the loop. If you wanted to call a function, you must write

```
reverseArray(arr, m);
```

Finally, note that when you do call `reverseArray`, your program might just instantly crash because `int arr2 [100000000];` is too big (you are allocating 400MB on the stack). If you're using C99, you can make a VLA: `int arr2[m]`. Otherwise, you'll have to `malloc` a temporary array and `free` it before returning.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take note of that in the future. I apologize for the simple question. One last thing though, after correctly calling the function and decreasing the allocation to the array to 20, the code still seems to crash. I was under the assumption that "return m" would change the value of m in the while loop, and might run it again if it wasn't equal to 1. Is this not true?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way to fix it. I changed the return value of my void function to arr[10] and added a m=arr[0] to the while loop. Again, sorry for the questions.